# "Nothing PROVIDES" in the own layer in the yoctoproject

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I had try to include my own layer for "Raspberry Pi Zero Wifi" in the yoctoproject. The layer must change
the default /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf onto one pressetted.
I had build the layer with follows files:

```
.
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-etc
    └── wpasupplicant
        ├── files
        │   └── wpa_supplicant.conf-sane
        └── wpasupplicant_0.1.bb
```

The wpasupplicant_0.1.bb have next context:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
#FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "$(THISDIR)/files:"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := "$(THISDIR)/files"

SRC_URI += "file://wpa_supplicant.conf-sane"

do_install(){
        install -d ${D}/etc
        install -m 0644 $(WORKDIR)/wpa_supplicant.conf-sane $(WORKDIR)/
}
```

When I have try to build the layer with bitbake, showed next message:

```
$ bitbake ../meta-rpi0W_inc-test-v3
Loading cache: 100% |#########################################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 684 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |#######################################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:39
Parsing of 2196 .bb files complete (401 cached, 1795 parsed). 3350 targets, 361 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES '../meta-rpi0W_inc-test-v3'

Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code
```

Could somebody explain me what is wrong?

Comment: `bitbake wpa-supplicant`

Comment: Hi Oleksandr. Thanks for advice. But isn't describe what is wrong into the  file 
 wpasupplicant_0.1.bb

Comment: you're trying to build the meta-layer, while you need to build the recipe (wpa-supplicant)